# How to set bracket to negative value but '-' should not be visible in birt report?

Tags: styles, format, birt, negative-number

I am using birt 4.4.1, and designing in eclipse. I am in a situation where i need to show a number enclosed by bracket if it is negative and also the "-" sign should not be shown(as we can do in microsoft excel). Is this possible in birt report?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your data item -> properties -> Format number -> custom

In "Format code" field enter two patterns separated by a semi-colon. The first pattern is for positive numbers, the second one for negative. For instance this pattern is a percent format, with brackets surrounding negative values.

```
0.0%;(0.0%)
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what i expect..Thanks Dominique..Please help me by give some good resources to learn BIRT for this kind of styling reports...